# Circuitikz - drawing error with complex circuit

Tags: circuitikz

If I try to compile the circuit in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51133/74786) answer, it gives me the weird error:

```
Undefined control sequence \draw
```

on the line

```
\draw (oa.+) -| (gnn) node[ground]{};
```

and the following ones.

I exactly copied the code in the answer, compiling it as it is, without modifications.

Is it normal? How could it be fixed?

Comment: Load `circuitikz` with option `siunitx` and use that integration as designed: `V=1<\volt>`, for example. The syntax may have changed since that answer was posted, which could explain the error.

Comment: @PaulGessler Thank you, it works! Do you want to write an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `siunitx` integration has changed since the answer in question was written. Nowadays, you can use `siunitx` conveniently with `circuitikz` by loading `circuitikz` with the option `siunitx` and then using syntax of the form

```
R=1<\kilo\ohm>
```

and similarly for the others. These changes make the error message go away. Here's the fully corrected code:

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage[american,siunitx]{circuitikz}  
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}  

\begin{document}  
\begin{circuitikz}[on grid]  
\draw   (0,1) node {Basic opamp};  
% Define coordinates and nodes  
\node (vi)  {};   
\node (a) [right=2 of vi] [label=below:$a$]{};  
\node[ground](gnn)  [below=1.0 of a,xshift=5mm] {};  
\node[ground](gnp)  [below=2.5 of vi] {};  
\node[op amp](oa)   [right=2 of a, yshift=-5mm]{};   
\node (vo)  [right=0.6 of oa.out]{};  
\node[ground](gnd)  [below=2 of vo] {};  

% connect coordinates, inputs, outputs, and components, i.e. draw the circuit  
\draw (gnp) to[V=1<\volt>] (vi);  
\draw (vi)  to[R=1<\kilo\ohm>] (oa.-);   
\draw (oa.+) -| (gnn) node[ground]{};  
\draw (oa.out)  to[short]   (vo);  
\draw (vo)  to[R=1<\kilo\ohm>]  (gnd);  
\end{circuitikz}  
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update:** Maybe my code style is less than ideal or a little bit esoteric, but here is how I personally would code your circuit:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[american,siunitx]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz} \draw
  (0,0) node[op amp] (oa) {}
  (oa.out) to[short] ++(0.6,0) coordinate (vo)
  (oa.-) coordinate (a) node[below] {$a$}
  to[R,l_=1<\kilo\ohm>] ++(-2,0) coordinate (vi)
  ++(0,-2.25) node[ground] (gnp) {}
  to[V=1<\volt>] (vi)
  (vo) to[R=1<\kilo\ohm>] (vo |- gnp)
  node[ground] (gnd) {}
  (oa.+) to[short] ++(-0.25,0) node[ground] (gnn) {}
;\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

The output is slightly different because I changed some spacings to my taste:

[image]